# How can I select text in Freda?

Tags: ebook-readers

I installed Freda reader in my PC with Windows 10 and my phone with Android. I cannot select text in any of the two devices. When I try to select a text, Freda interprets that I want to change the page. How can I select text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click `...` in the bottom right corner. Select `CONTROLS`, `swipe action`, press the button to the right, and choose `select`.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you want to keep the swipe-to-change page behaviour, and to be able to select text too, do this:

1. Hold (long-tap) or right-click on a word.
2. The word will be selected and selection handles will pop up each side of the word.
3. Drag the handles until you have selected exactly the text you want.
4. Tap on the selected text, or one of the handles, in order to apply an action
   (highlight, bookmark, look up, copy ...) to the selected text.
5. Or tap anywhere else, in order to un-select.